# Windows server reboots itself when logging for the first time

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain

On my domain servers that I use the administrator account there's no problem but logging from my house to the servers sometimes I have to use my personal domain user. The problem is when I log in for first time the server reboots... After that I can log in without any problem.

Is there any way to prevent that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it reboot when you log in with the Admin account, or do you have to log in with a non-admin account, and then it reboots?

Comment: Reboots when I log in with an domain account different to the administrator account.

Comment: The Windows Event Log will tell you who/what requested the reboot. What does it say?